# How can I confirm validity of deployed contract?

Tags: mist, contract-deployment

I have deployed contract using mist browser 0.6.1

How can I do code validity check on ethereum mist?

Comment: Did you test the contract using the test-net already?

Comment: Not yet, it is very simple contract, so I checked it twice and just deployed it to real network.

Comment: By validity check do you mean verifying the contract with a 3rd party website?

Comment: What exactly do you want to validate?

Comment: Consider making the answer as correct, if it solved your query.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is in the [web3.js documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract).

rough outline:

1. You will need:  your contract's ABI and code created by solidity.
2. call `web3.eth.contract()` with the ABI to create a web3.js contract instance.
3. Call the `.new()` function on your contract instance with contract constructor parameters
4. Verify the transaction hash and the address for the blockchain contract instance created with the `.new()` function.
5. Wait a few blocks (12 or so) and verify the code is there using  `web3.eth.getCode()`.  Compare the code to what you sent.

This outline of course is for web3.js, but in general you could do the same or similar steps in the geth console, from python, or one of the blockchain browsers.